# Why Mobile Location object is null though location is enabled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions

when I turn on GPS myself, Location object is not null
but
when I get self permissions, Location object is null though I can see it is enable in app settings.

I know that this may return null.

```
mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

The last known location can be null if there is no actual last known position or the ephemeris (one of the types of data GPS uses... think there are two but i don't remember what the other kind is called) data is stale and thus considered inaccurate.

So basically what i am saying in normal terms is that you can't always rely on the last known location to exist. Instead when it is found null, you should use the Fused API to find the current location according to the accuracy and tuning you want. You will find plenty of tutorials on this aspect and it is out of scope to explain how to do it here.